# An electrical system consists of two components in series.

Tags: probability

An electrical system consists of two components in series. The probability that the first component is defective is 2% and the probability of the second component is defective is 1%.

**a) What is the probability that the system is defective?**

To increase system reliability, we decided to put three identical components in parallel in the first and two identical components in the second (components are clearly independent).
**b) What is the probability that the system is not defective?**

**c) If the system is defective, what is the probability that is due to the second component ?**

Comment: interesting question. Did you try to solve it?

Comment: Too many "whats". Please show what you've tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Defective rate $= 0.02 + 0.01 = 3\%$

b) Defective rate $= 0.02^3 + 0.01^2 = 0.000008 + 0.0001 = 0.000108 = 0.0108\%$

Non-defective rate $=99.9892\%$

c) Probability of defect caused by the second component $= {0.0001\over 0.000108}=92.6\%$

Comment: Why in b) the Defective rate is not something like this =(0.02)^3+(0.01)^2- (((0.02)^3)*((0.01)^2)).

Comment: @RichardA.Torres Yes, you're correct. However, the 3rd number would be too small to affect the answer so I think you can ignore it.